# How to split pandas data frame by many criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I have ~150,000 rows of data detailing email bounces by domain, email template, bounce type and the count of each by day.  It is formatted like the below:

```
+--------+-------------+-----------------+-------+---------+-------+
|   t    | bounce_type |    source_ip    |  tid  |  emld   | count |
+--------+-------------+-----------------+-------+---------+-------+
| 1/1/15 | hard        | 199.122.255.142 | 10033 | aol.com |     4 |
+--------+-------------+-----------------+-------+---------+-------+
```

What is the easiest way to select only rows with an emld of "aol.com", bounce type of "hard", from all source ips and all tids?  Is this something I would create a function for and pass the dataframe through, or is there a simpler operation to filter the data by these criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way is to perform a masked, supposed your DataFrame called `df`, it will be something like this:

```
masked = (df['emld'] == 'aol.com') & (df['bounce_type'] == 'hard')
# then the result will be
df[masked]
```

shorthanded version in one line:

```
df[(df['emld'] == 'aol.com') & (df['bounce_type'] == 'hard')]
```

To just return `source_ip` and `tids` columns:

```
df[masked][['source_ip', 'tids']]
```

Or,

```
df[(df['emld'] == 'aol.com') & (df['bounce_type'] == 'hard')][['source_ip', 'tids']]
```

Hope this helps.